# Can you bind prop to childcomponent with router-view? (vue)

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

I have three Views that depend on data from the parent but I never want to show a view from more than one of these children.

## Parent

Fetch Api and manipulate the data. Store it as an array of objects in the data( ) object.
Containers role is to fetch api on created() and act as a parent to the views.
Data is shared with children. And header is imported as a component. The Children Components is rendered in the in router-views.
The data is stored in array of objects, userData[]

**Childcomponent 1 .**

path: /#/user

Needs userData[], to spit out content of users. You can click on a user, then you go to childcomponent2

**childcomponent 2.**

path: /#/user:id
Show specific userdata. Needs the userData[] array of objects.

**childcomponent 3.**

path: /#/user:id/list/:id

Show specific data of a list that a user has, needs userData[] for name and info of the user, and also make a new API-call for to get the list-items

Or what is the best architecture to set this up?

```
<template>
  <div>
    <UserView :listdata="item" v-if="bool" />
<ListView :listdata="item" v-if="bool" />
    <router-view></router-view>
  </div>
</template>
```

One other thing I thought of was to set a v-if="boolean" to display different views of it´s not possible to have children use prop of you just use the router-view and set them as children there,

```
export default [
  {
    path: "/",
    component: TheContainer,
    children: [{ path: "/user", component: UserView }, 
    { path: "/user/:id", component: ListView }],
  },
];
```

Answer (score 2):

You can bind props to the `<router-view>` which get forwarded to the child component it renders.

```html
<router-view :userdata="whatever">
```

Otherwise for more complicated tasks, you might need a global shared state (e.g. Vuex).

Comment: Aha ok great, but I cant get to work.

If I in the container have userData[ ] as data() object, and I want to reach it in UserView.vue to an prop named array1 there.

how do I write ? <router-view :userData="array1"> </router-view>
?

How do I write

Comment: Other way around, the child component prop is called `array1` so it would be `<router-view :array1="userData">`.